# Creating an IntelliJ Run Configuration for Angular and WebLogic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, intellij-idea, weblogic, angular-cli

I'm trying to create a run configuration in IntelliJ that will build my projects and run both ng serve (Angular CLI) and WebLogic Server simultaneously. I have installed the Multirun plugin in IntelliJ that allows multiple run configurations. I was able to create a run configuration for WebLogic Server however I cannot figure out a way to create a configuration that simply runs Angular CLI since it is ran through a command line.

Is there a plugin that I could use to initiate Angular CLI in intelliJ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up finding a solution to this issue. The only way that I could think of for running Angular CLI through a Run Configuration was to create a .cmd that opens up command prompt and starts the server. I stored this .cmd file within the project that needed Angular CLI and made that file my startup script in the WebLogic configuration. The same has to be done for the "Run" startup script and the "Debug" startup script.

When run (green arrow) is clicked, WebLogic runs inside of IntelliJ and a separate command prompt window opens and runs the Angular CLI.